# How to do runtime linking in make using LDFLAGS -R option, or some other way

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, linker, installation, tmux

This is a question on run time linking in make, in general.

I am trying to install tmux from source, on a linux system. It has dependency on "libevent" which I have installed in home dir. I am not the root on this system so I can't install it in system wide area.

DIR=$HOME/libevent
./configure --prefix=$HOME/site/tmux/ CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib/"

Though above command works but I need to have $HOME/libevent included in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH all the time for tmux to work. I think there should be a better way.

I need a run time linking so that I don't have to mess with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I read here http://www.ilkda.com/compile/Environment_Variables.htm that, this can be achieved using "-R" option.

./configure --prefix=$HOME/site/tmux/ CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib/" LDFLAGS="-R$DIR/lib/"

But this is not working and produces the following error:
configure: error: "libevent not found"

Can someone let me know how to do run time linking in make while running configure script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib/" LDFLAGS="-R$DIR/lib/"

The sets `LDFLAGS` to `-L$DIR/lib/`, and then *immediately* overrides it with `-R$DIR/lib/`, not unlike `x = 1; x = 2;` results in `x == 2`.

What you want is: `LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib/ -R$DIR/lib/"`

> "libevent not found"

I trusted you to read the man page, but you didn't. The `-R` flag means `RUNPATH` to linker on Solaris, but it means something *else* to Linux linker.

What you want then is:

```
LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib/ -Wl,--rpath=$DIR/lib/"
```

Comment: I tried this syntax as well, but it says "libevent not found". There must be some way out.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Let me give it a try.